# Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead

Tags: android, eclipse

I have this error but I have no idea how to solve it. Is there also the possibility for someone to explain to me what does this error mean? The erro is in the first line for "setOnClickListener" and then the last line where eclipse looking for a @ (??). Thanks to all

```
        backgroundA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                if (j < 2){ 
                    int randomInt1 = random1.nextInt(Deck.length());
                    int drawableIDA = Deck.getResourceId(randomInt1, -1);
                    backgroundA.setBackgroundResource(drawableIDA);
                    j ++;
            } else {
                choice1.setEnabled(false);
            }
            }           
            });
```

Where choice 1 is: final Button choice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.A); 
backgroundA is: final Button backgroundA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.A);

Comment: Which one'es the first line? Is View.OnClickListener an Interface or a Class?

Comment: It is in the class Game Activity, I need it for the interface, to press the button just two times.